# Calling Method in Subsonic 3.0 ActiveRecord Query

Tags: c#, linq, subsonic, subsonic3

I'm trying to run a custom method in subsonic query. Here is my query:

```
Page = Pages.SingleOrDefault(o=>Misc.MakeURL(o.Title) == URL);
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
The method 'MakeURL' is not supported
```

I'm using Subsonic 3. Any ideas would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply not possible,

subsonic translates your expression to SQL, so

```
Pages.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Title == "title");
```

will propably generate a similar query like this

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE title = 'title' LIMIT 1
```

and you are expecting subsonic to convert your MakeUrl(...) method into SQL. What do you expect?

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE MAKEURL(title) = 'title' LIMIT 1
```

However, you can either just query the title or call ToList() on your pages, but that will pull all records from the database.

```
Page = Pages.ToList().SingleOrDefault(o=>Misc.MakeURL(o.Title) == URL);
```